# Under a bright sun, can we see the shadow of an overhead power line on the floor?

Tags: everyday-life, diffraction

I once asked this question a long time ago to my teacher. He did not have a definitive answer, but started by considering the sun rays as parallel, and offered diffraction as a component of the solution.

To me, the sun rays could not be considered as parallel, as the diameter (or angular diameter) of the sun is not negligible, nor is the diameter of the power line. If so, the solution should only be a matter of simple trigonometry.

We ended our conversation without a definitive conclusion on this. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason you'll have a hard time finding a visible indication is the size of the sun's disk. A point on the floor for which the center of the sun is blocked from view can easily see both edges. (This is the same reason that even for "total" solar eclipses there are places where you see only a partial eclipse.)

When the width of the wire as seen from the ground is much smaller than the diameter of the sun then all the floor gets a significant fraction of full illumination, and the logarithmic response of your visual system surpresses the small difference.

Comment: So you agree with the problem being a trigonometry one? Say I lay on the floor, and we have a very thin power line: no shadow. Then we start _magically_ widening the power line. A shadow should appear on the floor as soon the line "eclypses" the sun, right? Or will we have to widen it more to compensate for other physic phenomenon?

Comment: Well, diffraction is occurring but you can't see diffraction patterns because of (a) the broad band nature of sunlight and (b) the geometry. On top of which the lack of visual contrast is compounded by the nature of the eye's response—you'd have a easier time detecting the diffuse penumbral shadow with a linear photometer than by eye.